# Using any ignite filter throws exception with the query

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am querying an ignite cache like this:

```
            try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, IgniteAccountOrder>> qryCursor = cache.query(new ScanQuery<>())) {
                qryCursor.forEach(
                        entry -> System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()));
            }
```

This works fine and the value gets serialized fine.

As soon as any filter is added to the query an exception occurs. Here is the exact same code with a filter that always returns true which is technically equivalent to the above code without any filter:

```
            IgniteBiPredicate<Long, IgniteAccountOrder> filter = (key, p) -> true;

            try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, IgniteAccountOrder>> qryCursor = cache.query(new ScanQuery<>(filter))) {
                qryCursor.forEach(
                        entry -> System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue()));
            }
```

The following exception occurs with the second code:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException: Ignite failed to process request [4]: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda] (server status code [1])
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.convertException(TcpClientChannel.java:336)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:296)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:218)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.lambda$service$1(ReliableChannel.java:165)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:763)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:731)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:164)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.GenericQueryPager.next(GenericQueryPager.java:93)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.nextPage(ClientQueryCursor.java:93)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.hasNext(ClientQueryCursor.java:76)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)

Comment: Can you please check server-side logs and include exception details from there?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that IgniteAccountOrder class was not available to the remote server.

I was connecting to the remote server via a thin client and peer loading could not be enabled for the thin client.

I did the following to make this work:

1. Switched to a thick client
2. Enabled peer class loading via the thick client:

```java
       IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
       cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
```